# Splitting one csv file according to different headers

Tags: powershell

I have a `csv` file with content in 3 different headers.
Ex:

```
Name,city,email----file 1-need to create separate csv file with content
aaa,ccc,eee@e
bbb,ddd,eee@e

-blank lines

Name,group,status----file 2-need to create separate csv file with content
aaa,xyz,active
aaa,abc,active
bbb,abc,active
ccc,xyz,active

Name,fullname,org----file 3-need to create separate csv file with content
aaa,aaaxc,ghj
xxx,fguh,dguyfgu
```

How I can split this csv into different 3 csv files with different headers by using PowerShell?

I tried by giving the row numbers to split but the content will be different in different files

Comment: Which result do you expect exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $content =   Get-Content "your File" -Raw
  $nl = [System.Environment]::NewLine
  $parts = $content -split ("$nl$nl") 
  $parts | % -BEGIN { $i=0} -PROCESS { $_ |  out-file "file_$($i++)).csv" -Append}
```

Comment: You should remove the spaces after the dashes

Comment: do I need provide any condition?getting error in the second line-You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.

Comment: Removed blanks after the dashes, please try it again. I tested it [online] (https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8nc3DyhKCEPhHOBQElBt7ggJ7NEITq4srgkNVfPNa8ssyg/Lzc1ryTWysovtdwnMy/1/38A). Should work.

Comment: it is creating only one file with one line(last line is present in this file)

Comment: I forgot the Append switch. Updated my answer.